# OnItemClickListener Cannot instantiate the type AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I have OnItemClick attacked to a listview and within the onItemClick() it opens a dialog with radio buttons, Cancel and Select. Within the dialog, I guess i need some sort of clickListener or itemSelectedListener so I can pass the value of the listview item they selected.

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,  long id) {
                if(position == 0) { 
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.cbRowCheckBox);
                    checkBox.setChecked(!checkBox.isChecked());
                }
                if(position == 1) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.sync_frequency);

                    ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener());  <-----
                    String[] syncOptions = mSyncOptions;
                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, android.R.id.text1, syncOptions);
                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(modeAdapter, 0, null);
                    builder.setView(listView);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.sync_select,null);
                    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.sync_cancel,null);
                    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

But I get an error saying Cannot instantiate the type AdapterView.OnItemClickListener. What is the best route or how can I fix this so I can let the code know which radio button the user selected? Thanks!

Comment: you should need to override `onItemClick` method of  OnItemClickListener

Comment: The @override is there at the top

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a `listener` to use when a `RadioButton` is `checked`. For this use, [onCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html)

You can use the second parameter to get the `id` of the `RadioButton` that was checked then you can do whatever you need with it from there.

```
yourRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
    { 
        if (checkedId == R.id.some_id)
        {
            // do something
        }

    });
```

Comment: The radios are generated in the android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice. How would I go about selecting the listView and putting a listener on the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

`AlertDialog`s have [built in support for lists](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) using the [setItems() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) - there's no reason to make your own custom `ListView`.